# use firebase database express

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I have node.js server using express and I want to use firebase to store data and later read it on client. I have read docs, but I can't figure it out.This is what I have.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');              
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://caos-27d19.firebaseio.com"
});
app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

const db = admin.database();
```

My question is how to store some data to firebase cloud when I have created the first document on the firebase console.

Comment: "i have created first document on firebase console" That sounds like you're using Cloud Firestore, which is based on collections of documents. But in your code you're using the Realtime Database, which stores JSON trees. Both databases are part of Firebase, but are completely separate aside from that, with their own APIs and documentation. To store data in the Realtime Database, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write. To store data in Firestore, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data.

Comment: thank you, it is working now!